# Flutter: How to update widgets when their content arrives from Google Firestore?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, builder

OK so my mission is, 
1. download a Record from Firestore, 
2. process this into state variables
3. inject data into widgets.

I've tried doing this by downloading stuff in initState, I made it Async, however the build method was then called before Firestore download completed, I didn't have the information ready for the widgets and it crashed.

I read that when a Widget is expected to change after being laid out, that I should use a Builder wrapper for the widgets.  Which brought me to this:

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(
                    "Job details")), // TODO might have to modify to accomodate edits
            body: _buildBody(context, widget.job.country, widget.job.area, widget.job.jobDetailedId, widget.job),
          );
}
```

So I'm calling buildBody with context for a Builder, seemingly I lose access to my this.job class object (why?!) so I pass some crucial parameters in for getting the Firestore record.

The aim of _buildBody is to download the firestore record, without using ASYNC await.  But it never executes any of the code beyond

> .then((jobrecord {

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, String countryCode, String area, String jobDetailedId) {
  Job detailedJob;
  Firestore.instance.collection("$countryCode/$area/JobsDetailed").document(jobDetailedId).get().then((jobRecord) {
  return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      if(jobRecord == null) {
        return Text("Document doesn't exist");
      }
      else {
        detailedJob = Job.fromSnapshot(jobRecord);
        detailedJob.jobDetailedId = jobRecord.documentID;
        return _screenBuild(context, detailedJob);
      }
  });
  });
}

Widget _screenBuild(BuildContext context, Job detailedJob) {
  return Text(detailedJob.description);
}
```

I thought .then would fire when Firestore returned the document, it doesn't fire.

Is this the best, most clear way of attacking the problem?  Would it be better to use a Future?  Or Asnc await from initState(), and then use setState()?

Comment: I would recommend you read up on [Future](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/Future-class.html). Also, a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc).

Comment: Thanks @Tomerpacific, I watched the video, and I got the code to execute in the .then( block, I needed to remove the builder wrapper.  However you can't return widgets to build() in this manner and have them displayed.  So it's a fair solution if only one Widget on your screen is dependent on an update, but not if many Widgets need updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet should do the work.

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, String countryCode, String area, String jobDetailedId) {
  Job detailedJob;
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("$countryCode/$area/JobsDetailed").document(jobDetailedId).snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              var jobRecord = snapshot.data.data; // contains document fields
              if(jobRecord == null) {
                return Text("Document doesn't exist");
              }
              else {
                detailedJob = Job.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data);
                detailedJob.jobDetailedId = jobRecord.documentID;
                return _screenBuild(context, detailedJob);
              }
            }
          });
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much @Yakub, yes this is exactly what I needed, I have multiple Widgets that need Firestore data, so this is the best solution.  Thanks for giving me something so complete with connection checking n' all that. X Sam.